# Campos que no tienen relacion sql Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Estoy intentando sacar una sql para Access que saque los registros que no tienen relacion, la clave de la references es Type,Anne,Numero y la otra tabla, article, tiene los campos: type, anne, numero, cle dossier
Yo he echo esto pero no me devuelve valores

```
SELECT *
  FROM articleEntreedescom
 WHERE not exists(select * 
                    from references_6851 
                    where (articleEntreedescom.Type = references_6851.Type)     
   AND (articleEntreedescom.nume = references_6851.Numéro) 
   AND (articleEntreedescom.Anee = references_6851.Année));
```

Comment: Deberías especificar un poco más que es lo que "no te funciona". ¿Te da error la sentencia? ¿No te devuelve valores? ¿Los valores que te devuelve no son correctos?

Comment: Esa consulta es correcta para sacar los registros de articleEntreedescom que no existen en references_6851 (siempre que los nombres de tablas y campos sean correctos). Lo que no te va a sacar son los registros de references_6851 que no existan en articleEntreedescom.
¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: En realidad es mas fácil encarar la solución buscando los que sí tengan relación y eso lo logras fácil con un  `INNER JOIN`

Comment: El objetivo es sacar una tabla con los registros de article que no tienen relación con los de references, mostrando esos registros de article

Comment: Los que ya tienen relación si que los había echo con el inner join

Comment: Asier Villanueva, tenias razón era correcta, e reiniciado el Access y la e puesto de nuevo y me ha funcionado, era algún error que me estaba dando Access